# Would it be acceptable to plant OC's mobile cache into GC's caches?

Tags: geocaching

I have currently no place of permanent perspective (from the geocache's point of view, I think it should be about 5 years, to be able to service cache in that time). So I'm thinking about creating the series of **mobile caches**. Of course, those caches can be created in **OpenCaching** only. And in Germany (the place I temporarily live in) it happens to be so, that **GeoCaching** is much more popular (not to say, dominant).

So I'm wondering if it is really a good idea to plant such mobile caches in the geocaches registered in GeoCaching.com.

I'm taking into account the following issues:

- how would the finder react to mobile cache, let's say in form of U-Ei? Would he/she know what to do with that (log in and, preferably, move to new location)? Or it is the risk that the cache would be thrown away as thrash?
- how would the cache owner react to such planting? Could it be considered rude or offensive?
- are there any objections, in general, against OpenCaching that make that portal so unpopular in Germany?

The preferable answer should address all the issues above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think OpenCaching is unpopular in Germany, just that GeoCaching.com seems to be the de facto portal in most regions.

If you mean a tag or chip that you pop in an existing cache with the intent that it be moved by the next visitor to the cache, I can't see a problem with that - it's pretty common the world over.

You just need to ensure that the mobile cache has brief instructions provided, for those who haven't seen one before. Ideally a URL and an ID number should be all that is required, but a brief comment to say what it is may be useful.